# How to convert each type in an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following types

```js
type ParseMustaches<T extends string[], U extends Record<string, string> = {}> = 
  T extends `{{${infer U}}}` 
    ? Record<U, string> 
    : never

type Test = ParseMustaches<["{{sitename}}", "{{user}}"]>

// expect Test to become { sitename: string, user: string }
```

I would like to return an object from this where all keys are required, the keys would be all inferred values and the values would be a string, how can I achieve this?
[playground using the TS version I am using](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88) and [link to PR that allows for inferring strings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Comment: Do you really need type? Why don't use class?

Comment: It's to type a parameter in a function, I don't need anything in runtime

Comment: Could you add sample input and expected output? It is not clear what's the problem/ not working

Comment: Added some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `T` is a tuple/array, so it doesn't extend the pattern, what you need to test is the tuple's item:

```
type ParseMustaches<T extends string[]> = 
  T[number] extends `{{${infer U}}}` 
    ? Record<U, string> 
    : never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QLIFcnDgYwBYRIA8AKlBAB7AQB2AJklFggJY0DmA2gLoB8UAXgBQUKCU410AWwBGEBN3JVaDKAAMA3hoAkGtgDN5UAKoBfc2pFQA-FABKEHAHsEdIsYA0TYKw68rAFxQNBAAbvJCQqCQYoTAgrCIKBhYuATEnABEWkgs1DRwUhDmmV7ZGpjyJXyRAPS1SpA48SRxUMBOUHLORVAaTHm0hRBBzGzsXpUIoz7jUKZAA)

Answer (score 0):

If you have little flexibility to change the way you call `ParseMustaches` then you can do this and get same result:

```js
type ParseMustaches<U extends keyof any> = Record<U, string>

type Test = ParseMustaches<'sitename' | 'user'>


// inferred
// type Test = {
//     sitename: string;
//     user: string;
// }
```

Comment: In that case he could do just `Record<'sitename' | 'user', string>`

Comment: yes, here `, string>` is additional :) but that works and maybe this is what he wants.

I cant visualize a case where/why I would need to do this `ParseMustaches<["{{sitename}}", "{{user}}"]>`

Comment: You can see the use case here https://sourceb.in/bbb29c89b0 @PritamKadam